# Можно ли сгенерировать xml из xsd?

Tags: java, xml

Есть xsd файл для ксш, с него нужно сгенерировать xml, как это можно сделать
Или можно ли сгенерировать java класс который будет заполнять xml

Вот начало xsd схемы

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2013 sp1 (http://www.altova.com) by AMD (Ru-Board) -->
<!--W3C XML Schema generated by XMLSpy v2013 sp1 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:simpleType name="Acc_Number_Type">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Номер/наименование счета</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="C">
        <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="AcctCur_Type">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Валюта счета</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="String">
        <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

на этом сайте требует https://devutilsonline.com/xsd-xml/generate-xml-from-xsd
указать корневой элемент которого вроде как нету

Comment: Онлайн инструменты есть http://xsd2xml.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В состав JDK входит [`xjc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html) - компилятор XSD в Java классы. Он находится в каталоге `$JDK_HOME/bin`. Использовать:

   `xjc path/to/file.xsd`

   На выходе получаются Java бины аннотированные [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/basic.html), которые вы можете использовать для генерации XML программно;
2. Если просто стоит задача разово сгенерировать тестовый XML по XSD, то проще воспользоваться одним из онлайн сервисов. [Вроде такого](http://xsd2xml.com/).
3. Использовать возможности IDE. [Например, для Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftcrexxsd.html): вызвать контекстное меню XSD файла, далее `Generate > XML file`.

---

Простенький пример генерации с помощью JAXB:

**test.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="country">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="country_name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="population" type="xs:decimal"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Применяем `xjc`, на выходе имеем Java-бины:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public ObjectFactory() {}

    public Country createCountry() {
        return new Country();
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "countryName", "population" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "country")
public class Country {

    @XmlElement(name = "country_name", required = true)
    protected String countryName;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigDecimal population;

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String value) {
        this.countryName = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(BigDecimal value) {
        this.population = value;
    }
}
```

Генерируем и проверяем:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, SAXException, IOException {

    // генерация XML
    ObjectFactory oFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    Country country = oFactory.createCountry();
    country.setPopulation(new BigDecimal(1000));
    country.setCountryName("NAME");

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Country.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.formatted.output", true);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(country, writer);
    String out = writer.toString();

    System.out.println(out);

    // валидация
    SchemaFactory sFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sFactory.newSchema(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd"));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(out)));
    System.out.println("XML valid");
}
```

Вывод:

```
<country>
    <country_name>NAME</country_name>
    <population>1000</population>
</country>
XML valid
```

Comment: Перехожу по ссылке хочу сгенерировать xml, вставляю xsd схему от ксш, он выдает мне две строки 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AgencyId>str12</AgencyId>
и все, хотя сама схема содержит более 1000 строк, обновил вопрос

Comment: @J Tan Вы определитесь что вам нужно: чтобы вам объяснили как можно сгенерировать схему, или чтобы сделали это за вас. Могу предположить, что 1000 строк это много, а на сервере стоит ограничение на размер POST. Пробуйте другие сервисы, гугл в помощь.

Comment: Можно погуглить офлайн тулзу или [возможность использлвать IDE](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftcrexxsd.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое, сгенерировало с xjc у меня много много классов, теперь  вопрос, у вас он сгенерировал один класс, а что делать если этих классов много и как понять как их надо строить

Comment: Это потому, что я взял самый простой случай для примера и класс у меня получился один. Как заполнять, не видя вашу схему, сказать невозможно. `xjc` должен был сгенерировать вам классы `ObjectFactory`. Заполнять нужно объекты, которые возвращаются методами `create***()` этих классов.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял вас, я заполняю все эти объекты к примеру два объекта создал, подскажите как мне их объединить в один xml, что надо делать с контекстом или без jaxbcontexta?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду сериализовать список объектов? Обернуть в отдельный класс. Задайте отдельный вопрос и приведите пример классов и XML который должен получиться.

Comment: я имею ввиду как сделать так же как в вашем примере но только не для одного класса а для двух классов

Comment: Ответ аналогичный. У XML всегда должен быть root. Для того чтобы сериализовать два разных типа, их нужно обернуть в отдельный класс. Если опираться на пример, то представьте, что countryName и population не строки, а Java классы.

Comment: я понял так что корневой элемент это где написано

      @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "")
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Properties")
    public class Properties
       extends PropertiesType
    {


    }

но у него нет методов ни каких, ни add ни set, что мне с ним делать

Comment: Обычно есть описание API, в котором написано какие объекты отправлять, и что придет в ответ. Нет нужной оберки запроса / ответа - напишите собственную. Если есть сложности с пониманием JAXB,, пожалуйста, задайте отдельный вопрос - на этот я уже ответил. Вы спросили "как сгенерировать", а не "как взаимодействовать с конкретной системой". Обсуждать детали вашей реализации не имея никаких данных по меньшей мере непродуктивно.

Comment: Понятно спасибо

Comment: подскажите пожалуйтста можно ли как то вывести xml из xsd используя вот Shema factory?

Comment: Нет, вроде бы. Это входная точка для получения валидатора XML документа.

Comment: понятно спасибо